# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a website with react Js but I got an error when I try to click on the image that I want to leave a comment it says **TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**
is anyone that can help me to figure out, please!

this is the code.

thank you!

```
<div className="content-margined">
    <h2>Reviews</h2>
    {!product.reviews.length & <div>There is no review</div>}
    
    <ul className="review" id="reviews">
        {product.reviews.map((review) => (
            <li key={review._id}>
                <div>{review.name}</div>
                <div>
                    <Rating value={review.rating}></Rating>
                </div>
                <div>{review.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</div>
                <div>{review.comment}</div>
            </li>
        ))}
        <li>
            <h3>Write A Commnet</h3>
            {userInfo ? (
                <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                    <ul className="form-container">
                        <li>
                            <label htmlFor="rating">Rating</label>
                            <select
                                name="rating"
                                id="rating"
                                value={rating}
                                onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
                            >
                                <option value="1">1- Poor</option>
                                <option value="2">2- Fair</option>
                                <option value="3">3- Good</option>
                                <option value="4">4- Very Good</option>
                                <option value="5">5- Excelent</option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label htmlFor="comment">Comment</label>
                            <textarea
                                name="comment"
                                value={comment}
                                onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                            ></textarea>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button type="submit" className="button primary">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    Please <Link to="/signin">Sign-in</Link> to write a review.
                </div>
            )}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the image you want to click? not able to find it in your code

Comment: also you have to add `javascript` code for handling the click event

Comment: is product.reviews is an array? if it is an object then try this product.reviews && product.reviews.length < 0

Comment: there is a gallery website I make it when user love the image if they want to leave a comment, first, they should click on the image then write a comment on the comment button, then it should show the name of the user who commented and the reviews, this is what i want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first your product does not have object `reviews` therefore `product.reviews` is undefined. To fix this you will have to first check if product has reviews object like this:

`product.reviews && product.reviews.length`

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I try as you said. TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, what I should do, please?

Comment: @MurtazaHassani Just like this check, you will have to again check before mapping: product.reviews.length && product.reviews.map

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the responsibility that you replay very quickly, my issue fixed

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that `product.reviews` is `undefined` during rendering and therefore has no attribute `length`. You need to either make sure that `product.reviews` always is an array or check if it is defined first:

```
{!product.reviews || product.reviews.length === 0 && <div>There is no review</div>}
```

and

```
{product.reviews && product.reviews.map( ...
```

Comment: Hey I try your code again it says 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @MurtazaHassani Of course you also need to check if it is an array before mapping over it. Updated my answer. I thought that would be clear as the error is very verbose about what is the issue. It might be better to simply ensure it always is an array then to check it everywhere.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick reply kind people love you so much, my issue fixed by your answer, thank you so much again :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in line 3, `product.reviews.length` is causing the error, as `product.reviews` is `undefined` and thus the `length` can't be found.

Depending on what that `product` object is, and what you want to happen, you could try adding `!product.reviews ||` before the length check, to cover the case where it is empty.

Comment: Hey yes you're correct it's in line-3, could you please tell me how exactly should I write this code? Thank you so much

Comment: Another answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874688/13892264 has written the code out for you, check it out.